# A non well formed numeric value encountered php7

Tags: php

I am running into issues with php 7 I get the following errors below.

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: A non well formed numeric value encountered
>
> Filename: controllers/Servers.php
>
> Line Number: 2155
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /httpdocs/application/controllers/Servers.php Line: 2155
>   Function: imagettftext
>
> File: /httpdocs/index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

this is line 2155

```
imagettftext($im,7,0,394,15,$color_title,'assets/fonts/arialbd.ttf',"# OF PLAYERS (past 24 hours)");
```

this is line 315

```
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';



// Main function for banners -  create banner
    public function createBanner(){
        // Get variables 
        $serverid = $this->uri->segment(2,0); // Server ID
        $color_title = $this->uri->segment(3,'FFC200'); // Color Title
        $color_info = $this->uri->segment(4,'FFFFFF'); // Color Info
        $bg = $this->uri->segment(5,'general_background'); // Background    
        $gradient_up = $this->uri->segment(6,'808080'); // Gradient_up  
        $gradient_down = $this->uri->segment(7,'000000'); // Gradient down  
        $border_color = $this->uri->segment(8,'000000'); // Border Color
        $border = $this->uri->segment(9,'false'); // Border ?   
        // Get Website Details
        $run = $this->db->get('settings');
        $site = $run->row();
```

Comment: Make sure `$color_title` is an `int` value. Line **315** is not the problem.  See [imagettftext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) for more information.

Comment: I'm not even sure where to look on this script

Comment: Search for `$color_title` and see where it's value is being set.  Troubleshoot from there (`echo $color_title; die();` or whatever you prefer).

Comment: Kraang Prime that's all I found I updated question

Comment: On the page you are testing, looks like the 3rd URI segment isn't a valid value.  Also, not 100% sure but I don't believe you can pass hex values to `imagettftext` . Bit of digging, and definitely it doesn't take hex colors directly.  You can translate them using `imageColorAllocate` see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php#94785)

Comment: it works fine on php 5.6 just not on php 7

Comment: Likely your php 5.6 is configured to ignore such errors, in which case the color would be default (black i think). From the code you have supplied, the `non well formed numeric value` is a hex code or whatever the 3rd segment in your url is, when `imagettftext` is expecting an `int` for the 6th param. *The color index. Using the negative of a color index has the effect of turning off antialiasing. See imagecolorallocate().*